# Why my csv file is blank?

Tags: apex, dynamic-visualforce, csv

I try to pass on a list to a new visualForce page and then display that list as a table to download as a csv file. But I am getting blank csv file. As soon as i redirect to my new page the list gets empty even though "setRedirect=false". Following is my code:
Controller code:

```
    public class PaginationForComponent {
  public PaginationForComponent(){
    allContactList = new list<wrapper>();
    myOrder = 'desc';
    sortField='name';
    PageNumber = 1;
    alphabet = new list<string>{'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','Others','All'};
    RecordsPerPageslist = 10;
    System.debug('constructor called');
  }
  Boolean lstNamePresent=false;
  public String objName{get;set;}
  public String fieldNames{get;set;}
  list<sObject> con = new list<sObject>();
  public String alphaSearchConct{get;set;}
  public string msg {get;set;}
  public Map<id,Boolean> m = new Map<id,boolean>(); 
  list<sObject> sortedList;
  public String myOrder{get;set;}                 // Ascending or Descending order of sorting
  public String sortField{get;set;}               // Field by which sorting should be done
  public boolean selectAll{get;set;}
  public list<String> alphabet{get;set;}
  public list<sObject> cont;
  public list<wrapper> allContactList{get;set;}
  public list<wrapper> ct = new list<wrapper>();
  public list<wrapper> csvList{get;private set;}
  public list<String> query;
  public list<String> csvQuery{get;private set;}
  public Integer PageNumber{
          get{                                                            //To get current page number
              System.debug('get of pageNumber called '+ PageNumber); 
              if(ApexPages.getMessages().size()==0){
              return this.PageNumber;
              }
              else{
                  return PageNumber;// edit this for current page url
              }
          }
          set{  
              System.debug('set of pageNumber called '+ value);
              this.pageNumber=value;         
          }
      }    
    public Integer TotalPages{                                            // Total number of pages as per user selection of Records per page
          get{
               System.debug('TotalPages called'); 
              if(stdSetController.getResultSize() <=10)
                     this.TotalPages=1;
                if(Math.Mod(stdSetController.getResultSize() ,stdSetController.getPageSize()) == 0)
                    this.TotalPages =(stdSetController.getResultSize()/stdSetController.getPageSize());
                else
                  this.TotalPages = (stdSetController.getResultSize()/stdSetController.getPageSize())+1;
                //System.Debug(this.TotalPages);
                  return totalpages;
          }
          set;
      }
    public Integer RecordsPerPageslist{ 
        get;
        set{                                                          //To select number of records per page
            if(value!=null){
                this.RecordsPerPagesList=value;
                System.debug('RecordsPerPageList called');
           }
        }       
    } 
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController stdSetController{            //Instantiating a standard set controller
          get{
              if(stdSetController==null){
                    //con = Database.query('SELECT '+ fieldNames+' FROM '+ objName );//del it from here update con from script n return allContactList by filling it from there only
                    System.debug('con in ssc is : ' + con);
                    stdSetController = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con);
              }
                stdSetController.setPageSize(RecordsPerPageslist);        //Limiting Number of records to be displayed per page 
                System.debug('stdSetController called and fieldNames are : ' + allContactList);
                return stdSetController;   
          }
          set;
    }
    public void SelectedListContacts(){         // Select contacts and save them in a map  
        for(wrapper wc:allContactList){
            m.put(wc.con.id,wc.isSelected);
          if(wc.isSelected==false){
              selectAll=false;
           }
        }
    }
    public void SelectedAllContacts(){          //To select all contacts in a page
        System.debug(selectAll);
        allContactList.clear();
        for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords()){
            allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
        }
        if(selectAll==true){
            for(wrapper wc:allContactList){
                m.put(wc.con.id,wc.isSelected=true);
        }
     }
     else{
        for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
            m.put(wc.con.id,wc.isSelected=false);
     }
    }
    public String[] getqueryList(){
    query = fieldNames.split(',');
    for(String s:query){
      if(s=='lastname'){
        lstNamePresent=true;
      }
    }
    return query;

  }
    public list<wrapper> getWrapperContacts(){      //List of wrapper class to display in table
      return allContactList;
    }

    public Integer stdSize(){
      Integer i = stdSetController.getRecords().size();
      return i;
    }

    public void docReady(){
      con = Database.query('SELECT '+ fieldNames+' FROM '+ objName );
      System.debug('docReady con is ' + con);
      for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
            allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      System.debug('docReady allContactList is ' + allContactList);
    }


    public void next(){
      System.debug('next');
      allContactList.clear(); 
      selectAll=false;       
      this.stdSetController.next();
      this.PageNumber=stdSetController.getPageNumber();
      for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
              wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
    }
    public void previous(){
     allContactList.clear();    
     selectAll=false;    
     this.stdSetController.previous();
     this.PageNumber=stdSetController.getPageNumber(); 
     for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
              wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
      }
    public void last(){
      System.debug('last called');
      allContactList.clear();        
      this.stdSetController.last();
      this.PageNumber=stdSetController.getPageNumber();
      for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
              wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
    }
    public void first(){
      System.debug('first called');
      allContactList.clear();        
      this.stdSetController.first();
      this.PageNumber=stdSetController.getPageNumber();
      for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
              wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id); 
    }
    public boolean getHasNext(){
      System.debug('getHasNext called');
      return stdSetController.getHasNext();
    }
    public boolean getHasPrevious(){
      System.debug('getHasPrevious called');
      return stdSetController.getHasPrevious();
    }
  public Pagereference alphaSearch() { //To update contact list as per the alphabet selected by the user

     System.debug('alphaSearch called');
     allContactList.clear();
     if (alphaSearchConct == 'All') {
         con = Database.query('SELECT ' + fieldNames + ' FROM ' + objName);
     }
     if(lstNamePresent){
        con = Database.query('SELECT ' + fieldNames + ' FROM ' + objName + ' WHERE name Like \'' + alphaSearchConct + '%\'');
     }
     else{
      msg = 'Last Name not present in the Column list';
     }
     ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(con);
     stdSetController = ssc;
     for(sObject c: (list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
      for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
           wc.isSelected=m.get(wc.con.id);
     return null;
  }
  public PageReference NavigateByText() { 
    allContactList.clear();
    System.debug('getNavigateByText ');
     try {
      this.stdSetController.setPageNumber(PageNumber);
      for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
            allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
          for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
                  wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
      }
      catch (Exception e) {
        msg = e.getMessage();
     }
      return null;
  }
  public list < SelectOption > getRecordsPerPageOptionList() { //To display a drop down list on vf page  
     list < SelectOption > options = new list < SelectOption > ();
     options.add(new selectOption('10', '10'));
     options.add(new selectOption('25', '25'));
     options.add(new selectOption('50', '50'));
     options.add(new selectOption('100', '100'));
     options.add(new selectOption('200', '200'));
     return options;
  }
  public Pagereference ChangeNumberOfRecordsPerPage() {
    allContactList.clear();
    for(sObject c:(list<sObject>)stdSetController.getRecords())
          allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
    for(wrapper wc:allContactList)
          wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
    PageNumber=1;
    return null;
  }
  public Pagereference DelSelected() {
      list < Id > c = new list < Id > ();
      try { 
        for (id i: m.keySet()) {
          if (m.get(i) == true) {
            c.add(i);
        }

       } 
        Database.delete(c);
      } 
      catch (System.DmlException e) {
        msg = e.getMessage();
      }
      return null;
   }
   // togglesort() for sorting of records
  public void toggleSort() {

     cont = Database.query('SELECT ' + fieldNames + ' FROM ' + objName + ' Order By ' + sortField + ' ' + myOrder);
     ApexPages.StandardSetController ssc = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(cont);
     ssc.setPageSize(RecordsPerPageslist);
     stdSetController = ssc;
     allContactList.clear();
     for (sObject c: (list < sObject > ) stdSetController.getRecords())
            allContactList.add(new wrapper(c));
     for (wrapper wc: allContactList)
            wc.isSelected = m.get(wc.con.id);
   //System.debug('togglesort called '+ stdSetController.getRecords());
  }
  public Pagereference submit() {
    csvList = new list<wrapper>();
    csvQuery = new list<String>();
    try {
    for (id i: m.keySet()) {
      System.debug('id is '+i);
      if (m.get(i) == true) {
        sObject c = Database.query('SELECT ' + fieldNames + ' FROM ' + objName + ' WHERE id= :i');
        ct.add(new wrapper(c));
        System.debug('ct is '+ ct);
      }
     }
    } 
    catch (System.QueryException e) {
     System.debug('Error while generating csv file ' + e);
    }
    csvList.addAll(ct);
    csvQuery.addAll(query);
    System.debug('csv list earlier ' + csvList);
    Pagereference pgReference = Page.ConvertToCSVController;
    PgReference.setRedirect(false);
    return pgReference;
    }
   // To convert to CSV file
  /*public list < wrapper > getgenerateCSV() {
    System.debug('csv list is :' + csvList);
    return csvList;
  }
  public String[] getqueries(){
    return csvQuery;
  }*/
    public class wrapper{
      public boolean isSelected{get;set;}  
      public sObject con{get;set;}  
      public   wrapper(sObject con){
              //System.debug('constructor of wrapper class called ');
              isSelected = false;
              this.con = con;
          }
    }
  }
```

VisualForce page code:

```
   <apex:page sidebar="false" controller="t1">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock id="pb">
            <b>Select Object Name </b> &ensp;&nbsp;
            <apex:SelectList value="{!ObjList}" size="1" disabled="{!objList!=null}">
              <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectList}">   
               </apex:selectOptions>
               <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="pb" action="{!createFldMap}"/>
            </apex:SelectList> &ensp;&nbsp;
            <apex:commandButton value="Reset" action="{!reset}" onclick="window.location.reload();" reRender="pb,component"/>
            <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!IF(objList==null,false,true)}" id="fList">
                <div align="left" style="width:500px; margin-right: 0px;">
                    <br/>
                        <b> Field's Labels </b>
                        <!-- To display all fields for an object -->
                        <apex:SelectList value="{!fldList}" multiselect="true" size="10" >
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!fieldList}"><br/>
                        </apex:selectOptions>
                    </apex:SelectList>
                    <!-- a list to display field values that are selected-->
                        <!-- To display all selection of fields-->
                        <span style="float:right;margin-right: 86px;margin-top:-14px;" rendered="{!SelectedfldList!=null}">
                            <b> Selected Fields </b>
                                <apex:SelectList value="{!dispSelectedfldList}" multiselect="true" size="10" >
                                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!SelectedfieldList}"><br/>
                                    </apex:selectOptions>
                                </apex:SelectList>
                        </span>
                    <span style=" float:right ;margin-top: 10%;margin-right: 37px;"> 
                        <apex:commandButton value=">>" action="{!addfldList}" reRender="pb"/> <br/>
                        <apex:commandButton value="<<" action="{!RemovefldList}" reRender="pb" />
                    </span>
                </div>
            </apex:pageBlock>
            <div align="left">
                <apex:commandButton value="Display" action="{!process}" reRender="component" />
            </div>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:outputPanel id="component">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Selectedflds!=null}">
            <c:Dynamic_pagination objectName="{!ObjList}" fieldName="{!Selectedflds}">
            </c:Dynamic_pagination>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel> 
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My  page code(on which it is redirected)

```
<apex:page controller="PaginationForComponent" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#contacts.xls" readOnly="True">
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!generateCSV}" var="csv">
            <apex:repeat value="{!queries}" var="fldNames">
                <apex:column value="{!csv.con[fldNames]}"/> 
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Visualforce page does not call the action method that performs work in your class, `submit()`.

The getter methods for the two properties you're iterating over, `generateCSV` and `queries`, both simply return the data that's stored in instance variables - they don't query the database or perform any work.

Since `submit()` is never called, both methods will simply return the empty lists that are created when your controller is instantiated, which you should see in your debug logs for `generateCSV()`.

You need to refactor your code to pull the CSV-generation logic out of `submit()` into a non-action method, say `generateData()`. Then, call that method from your class constructor to ensure the data is populated. However, I'll also note that you don't appear to be populating `fieldNames` anywhere, so you'll get a `QueryException`.

Based on your comments, you are using this controller for multiple pages and attempting to persist values in instance variables from one to the other. Unfortunately, Visualforce does not support sharing data in that fashion. When you redirect to that other page, an entirely new instance of your controller is constructed, with no data from the view state of the previous page. You'll have to rethink your architecture here - the only way you can pass data between these pages is by persisting it to the database or passing it in parameters.

Comment: Thanks David, actually i have been populating the fields, I didn't provided my complete code, but here it is now. My fields and objects are both dynamic so I don't think so getting through constructor is a good way. Here now I have updated my complete code

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything - you still don't call `submit()`. I suggest you think about this in terms of flow of control - when your page loads, what happens? Where in the sequence of events are your variables populated, and is that the right time for the data to be available?

Comment: On my First page(the one where "Submit" button is present) when i click the submit button an apex method named submit is called. In that method  I am initializing two new lists named csvList and csvQuery whose references are outside the method. Now when I am redirected to another page(PgReference.setRedirect(false);) I call these 2 lists holding previous values only but still I am getting blank values